# jQuery - Checkboxes are counting but not when clicking the check all checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a simple script to count all of the `.checkboxes` that have been checked. When they each are checked individually the count works just fine, but when I select the `.checkall` checkbox, it doesn't count. I did try changing the `$checkboxes` variable to `input[type=checkbox]` which counted incorrectly.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/rv4j8ghn/

Code:

```
      // Select all checkboxes
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.checkall').click(function(event) {  
          if (this.checked) {
            $('.checkboxes').each(function() {
              this.checked = true;
            });
          } else {
            $('.checkboxes').each(function() {
              this.checked = false; 
            });         
          }
        });      
      });

      // Count Checkboxes
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var $checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
        var checkall = $('.checkall:checked');

        $checkboxes.change(function(){ 
          var count = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;              
          $('.counted').val(count);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function (event) {    
    $('.checkboxes').prop('checked', this.checked);
    var $checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
    var count = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    $('.counted').val(count);
   });
});
```

You have to add checkbox checked count code inside checkall click event.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h7zprokf/2/